# I've built the libraries from source for macOS Xcode 10.2 but I can't get MIDI out to work. MIDI input seems fine

Tags: audiokit

I'm learning the AudioKit framework and it was necessary to build the framework from source as the 4.2 binaries aren't compatible with the 5.0 compiler in Xcode 10.2. I have not been able to Get MIDI output working to either a physical device or using a virtual port to another app.

I can't get the examples MIDI output playground to work. I get no errors but also no MIDI output
I'm using the following:

```
import AudioKitPlaygrounds
import AudioKit

let midi = AudioKit.midi

midi.openOutput()

import AudioKitUI

class LiveView: AKLiveViewController, AKKeyboardDelegate {

var keyboard: AKKeyboardView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    addTitle("MIDI Output")

    keyboard = AKKeyboardView(width: 440, height: 100)
    keyboard.delegate = self
    addView(keyboard)

    addView(AKButton(title: "Go Polyphonic") { button in
        self.keyboard.polyphonicMode = !self.keyboard.polyphonicMode
        if self.keyboard.polyphonicMode {
            button.title = "Go Monophonic"
        } else {
            button.title = "Go Polyphonic"
        }
    })
}

func noteOn(note: MIDINoteNumber) {
    midi.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(noteOn: note, velocity: 127, channel: 3))
    AKLog("sending note \(note)")
}

func noteOff(note: MIDINoteNumber) {
    midi.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(noteOff: note, velocity: 0, channel: 3))
}
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = LiveView()
```

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It turns out that AudioKit was actually sending on channel 4 instead of channel 3. Looks like the channel index is off by 1.
Per the developer MIDI channels are indexed from 0, not 1 so this is expected behavior